# Babel error in installation of Nuxtjs package

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js

I am trying to install Nuxt-Admin-starter and every time i am facing this error ,
my node version is 14.17.1 and the package i am trying to install is :
https://github.com/vrwebdesign/nuxt-admin-starter ,

how can i fix this ?

```
ERROR in ./.nuxt/client.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\babel-preset-app\src\polyfills-plugin.js:1
Error: C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\.nuxt\client.js: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/lib/utils'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\babel-preset-app\src\polyfills-plugin.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\babel-preset-app\src\index.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\nuxt.config.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\config\dist\config.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli.js
- C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\typescript-runtime\bin\nuxt-ts.js
    at PluginPass.Program (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@nuxt\babel-preset-app\src\polyfills-plugin.js:15:34)
    at newFn (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:179:21)
    at NodePath._call (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:90:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:84:17)
    at traverse (C:\Users\a\Desktop\New folder\nuxt-admin-starter\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:66:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

The given repo is not an NPM package, hence you cannot install it. It is actually a boilerplate starter, so a project that gives you some already configured existing structure for you to spend less time configuring things and alike.

The steps to successfully run the project are

```
[go to a clean "code" directory]
git clone https://github.com/vrwebdesign/nuxt-admin-starter
yarn
[pass the required "RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY" into a `.env` file otherwise it will error]
yarn dev
```

And this should do the trick for you to access the project.
It can either be your starting point or you can get some configuration from it but you will not be able to install it with something like `yarn add nuxt-admin-starter`.

Comment: or you can comment @nuxtjs/recaptcha module in nuxt.config.js